# How to consume 3party json services in GWT

Tags: gwt, jsonp, gwtquery, gquery

I'm looking for the best way in GWT to access a 3party json rest service and parse its response quickly. The rest service offers the `callback` parameter, and the example they gave us is using jQuery.jsonp:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://server_name?id=and_id&callback=?',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(js) {/*{id='id',status='sold',prod_name='name',price=0.0 ...}*/},
  error: function(e) {}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although GWT comes with a [JsonpRequestBuilder](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.html) to perform requests via script tags and [AutoBeans](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/AutoBean) to handle json responses and generate java implementations, I prefer [gwtquery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) [Ajax](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax) and [DataBinding](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/DataBinding) because of its simplicity.

In your case you could have almost the same syntax that your provider gave you:

```
  ajax("http://server_name?id=and_id&callback=?",
       $$("type:'get', dataType: 'jsonp'),
       new Function() {
        public void f() {
          Properties jso = getDataProperties();
          String status = jso.get("error");
        }
  });
```

If you prefer to use builders because you like get/setters your code could look like this:

```
  public static interface MResponse extends JsonBuilder {
    String getId();
    String getStatus();
    String getProd_name();
    double getPrice();
  }

  ajax(Ajax.createSettings()
           .setType("get")
           .setDataType("jsonp")
           .setUrl(""))
    .done(new Function() {
      public void f() {
        MResponse resp = GWT.<MResponse>create(MResponse.class)
                            .load(getDataProperties());
        String status = resp.getStatus();
      }
    });
```

Comment: Ah, I got it, it is necessary to import GQuery static methods